# Android/SQLite - "Managing Database in one place statically" vs "serialisation and intent method"

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have one general question:

what do you think about following two alternatives considering style and speed

- having a cached list in the main application and always using this list and load data on demand (and remove it on demand, for example if the cache get's to big)
- always serialise the data, adding it to the intent, give it to the sub activity, working on the data, serialise it again and give it back to the parent activity and replace the original data in the list with the one gotten back from the sub activity

in my case, i've probably always a list with a thousand entries... and about 5 levels into the deep... always serialising costs time... and i've to handle the changes, because the parent activity newer knows, if the data was changed in the sub activity...

the global data cache has the advantage, that I always and everywhere interact with the same objects and never have to take care, that if data is changed, that I update this data somewhere else...

Is that a bad idea? if so, why? I want to speed up my application and am thinking about changing it to this model...

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "serialise"?

Comment: implementing the `java.io.Serializable`-Interface... and giving the serialised object to the intent...

Comment: Ok, and how is the question related to SQLite?

Comment: it's about comparing speed of serialisation vs. reading from databse (if not cached)... and a question about the design idea...

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. I really don't understand what you try to do and why.

Comment: Actually, I know, global variables are not very beautiful... But I need some fast methods to hand on some database objects, sometimes quite many (like an object with a hundred subobjects)... now having a list that is accessible from everywhere, would make serialisation unnecessary... meaning, I don't have to hand on the object to the subactivity, edit it there, and send all (edited) objects back to the parent activity... instead, I always access the global list...